# The mysql error was: Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

The problem I have is that I'm still getting the message:

> Site off-line The site is currently not available due to technical
>   problems. Please try again later. Thank you for your understanding.
>
> If you are the maintainer of this site, please check your database
>   settings in the settings.php file and ensure that your hosting
>   provider's database server is running. For more help, see the
>   handbook, or contact your hosting provider.
>
> The mysqli error was: Access denied for user 'name'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES).

It happend after I accidentaly changed the password to mysql. Shortly after I'd noticed this, I reverted to the previous password which is THE SAME as the one in the settings.php file. But I still get the same message and I don't know why. Is there any other place where the password is kept? What else can be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct password? If so, try and restart.

Comment: changed the password where? in your php code? in the actual mysql user account?

Comment: mysql user account. But then reverted to the original password which is the same with the one in the settings.php file.

Comment: what method did you use to change the password each time?

Comment: Via my web hosting service's admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. I've changed the password one more time, but now it contains only letters and digits. And now it works fine.